# Разделить строку на целые числа Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть строка, которая записана таким образом: "23 54 67 87 64".
Как мне разделить эту строку на отдельные целые числа по пробелу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "23 54 67 87 64"

result = list(map(int, s.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [int(i) for i in "23 54 67 87 64".split()]
```